# Проблемы с подключением шрифтов

Tags: android

Подключил шрифты в своём проекте, в среде разработки новый гугловские шрифты отображаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а у меня на устройстве ( API 25) шрифты остаются стандартные

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/title_home"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/orbitron_black"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем же, ну зачем же вы вставляете такой большой скриншот? Разве трудно вырезать нужную часть?!

Comment: Требуется больше информации. Покажите разметку кодом, текстом. Покажите как вы подключили шрифты (структура папок, возможно xml файлы в ресурсах), подключили ли библиотеку поддержки и если да, то какую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб структуру и как подключаю скинул, сам шрифт качал через android studio

Comment: Попробуйте изменить `app:fontFamily` на `android:fontFamily`. И покажите содержимое `build.gradle` - может у вас вообще библиотека нужная не подключена.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло, gradle скинул

Comment: @Vadim, попробуйте тогда заменить TextView на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` и вернуть `app:fontFamily`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб УРААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА!!! Оформите как ответ пожалуйста!!! Можно узнать а почему в v7 сработало?

Comment: @Vadim, я не знаю почему так) По идее оно само должно подменяться на `v7`, но, возможно, для этого надо что-то где-то ещё менять, изучая документацию... Но у меня лично желания такого нет, засим у себя такой способ использую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае должно помочь изменение класса с `TextView` на `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`. Хотя по идее, оно само должно подменяться при использовании библиотеки поддержки.